# why android program can work on avd but failed to work on real machine

Tags: android

```
[2014-02-28 15:56:59 - Torch] Failed to install Torch.apk on device 'EC233D013E3B! 
[2014-02-28 15:56:59 - Torch] (null) [2014-02-28 15:56:59 - Torch] Launch canceled!
```

When the apk was  installed to real machine, it showed the above tips. I have set the avd's API level same with the real machine's API level.

Comment: i bet that the answer is in full adb logcat logs.

Comment: Because you have installed the app before and later changed the package name.  Uninstall first, then try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Uninstall the existing App in your AVD or ANdroid Device. The following are the reasons for your bug :

```
1) Your app might be still running and allocated memory may not be released properly.

2) If you have less memory of SD Card, RAM and Heap Size in your AVD will throw this error.

3) You might declared <uses-sdk minSDKVersion = "8" /> and you might running AVD with API < 8 also causes error.
```